# trying to call cloudwatch loggroupname and logstreamname in terratest with the help of awsgosdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-sdk-go

in the terratest, I want to call the aws cloud watch specific log group name and log stream name below code is from git hub but no idea how to call specific log group and log stream

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/go/example_code/cloudwatch/CloudWatchGetLogEvents.go

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
c := aws.NewCloudWatchLogsClient(t, awsRegion)
t.Run("logStreamExists", func(t *testing.T) {
        output, err := c.DescribeLogStreams(&cloudwatchlogs.DescribeLogStreamsInput{
            LogGroupName: &logGroupName,
        })
        if err != nil {
            assert.Fail(t, "Failed to get log streams")
        }
    var names []string
    for _, element := range output.LogStreams {
        names = append(names, *element.LogStreamName)
    }
    assert.Contains(t, names, logStreamName)
})
```